# Make a MUI <TextField /> convert input to uppercase

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Controller
    name="promoCode"
    control={form.control}
    render={({ field }) => (
        <TextField
            {...field}
            label={t('promoCode', { ns: 'promotionsAndDiscounts' })}
            data-testid="promoCode"
            InputProps={{
                sx: styles.promoCodeInput,
                endAdornment: (
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                        <Button
                            aria-label="generate promo code"
                            onClick={() => field.onChange(generatePromoCode())}
                            data-testid="generatePromoCode"
                            sx={styles.promoCodeBtn}
                        >
                            {t('generatePromoCode', { ns: 'promotionsAndDiscounts' })}
                        </Button>
                    </InputAdornment>
                )
            }}
        />
    )}
/>
```

I'd like to make  either not accept lower case letters, or convert them to upper case on the fly. I tried the following, without success:

```
onInput={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    field.onChange(e.currentTarget.value ? e.currentTarget.value.toUpperCase() : '');
}}
```

Comment: Do not try that, it'll break badly some IMEs (and probably another half-dozen regular cases we can't imagine right now). Use `text-transform: uppercase` (in your CSS) for display purposes and do a case insensitive comparison/search server-side (or call `toUpperCase()` before POSTing/using the code)